# RDLC report generation issue

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

Is there way in to display group name near each item of group ? [image]  for example in attached screenshot : display date not only for first item of the group ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the group header, you can hide the group column and add the `DATE` column as Details column.

Example: I use `sex` as group.

[image]

You can make the group column or fields invisible / very small width and add detail column on the right.

End result:

[image]